# redirect using .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect using .htaccess from a subfolder to another domain using the following code:

```
Redirect 301 / https://newsite.com
```

Subfolder name is `oldfolder`
When I click `http://website.com/oldfoler`, I'm redirectd to `https://newsite.com/oldfolder`. When I click on `http://website.com/oldfoler/about-us`, I'm redirected to `https://newsite.com/oldfolder/about-us`

My .htaccess file is located in `oldfolder`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because that is the default behavior of `Redirect`.

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect
>   request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional
>   path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the
>   target URL.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

You need to use `RedirectMatch` or `RewriteRule`.

So if you want to redirect `/oldfolder` to new domain you can do this.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/? http://newsite.com/
```

Comment: Yes but `/newsletters.php` getting added in target URL is weird

Comment: @anubhava I was already writing my answer before he updated his question.