# How to redirect a subdomain to inner page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my homepage to an inner page:
http://website.com/ to http://website.com/event/2/

How can I do this with .htaccess ?
PS: I do not have any file .htaccess in my website, so i'll create a new one.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [auto redirect to another html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895424/auto-redirect-to-another-html-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect using .htaccess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004548/redirect-using-htaccess-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

please add this code to your htacess `Redirect 302 / http://website.com/event/2//` !! for more information see this article 
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file